# breaking down an array of two arrays from input PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, postman

I posted array below with postman to my PHP API and it is stored perfectly and I can print_r and see it:

```
$sizes = [['new_width' => 100, 'new_height' => 300], ['new_width' => 400, 'new_height' => 200]];
```

how I stored the sizes

```
$sizes = $_POST['sizes'];
```

postman result from print_r($sizes):

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['new_width'] => 100
            ['new_height'] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['new_width'] => 400
            ['new_height'] => 200
        )

)
```

but when I want to see each array of size separately, I fail.

```
        foreach ($sizes as $size) {
            $size = [$_POST['new_width'], $_POST['new_height']];
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($size);
            die();
        }
```

this is what postman returns as result:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
)
```

so it obviously can't store new_width and new_height for size.
how can I do it the right way?

Comment: `$size` is already what you want. Just remove the line where you overwrite it with values from `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

In the foreach loop, you just have to use the `$size` variable instead of `$_POST`.

Try this:

```php
foreach ($sizes as $size) {
            $newTab = [$size['new_width'], $size['new_height']];
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($newTab);
            die();
        }
```